# Trouble creating and using a JNI library

Tags: java, java-native-interface

This is my java lib file:

`HelloWorldJNI.java`

```
package hello;

public class HelloWorldJNI {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("native");
  }

  public native void sayHello();
}
```

The corresponding bridging header and cpp files:

`HelloWorldJNI.h`

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorldJNI */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorldJNI
#define _Included_HelloWorldJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorldJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

`HelloWorldJNI.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "HelloWorldJNI.h"

void Java_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject object) {
  std::cout<<"Hello CPP!\n";
}
```

The directory structure is like so:

```
|-hello
|     -HelloWorldJNI.java
|     -HelloWorldJNI.h
|     -HelloWorldJNI.cpp
```

Compiled using:

```
g++ -c -fpic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux hello/HelloWorldJNI.cpp -o HelloWorldJNI.o
g++ -shared -fpic -o libnative.so HelloWorldJNI.o -lc
javac -h . hello/HelloWorldJNI.java
```

After deleting the `.java` `.cpp` and `.h` files from  the hello directory:

```
jar cvf hello.jar ./hello
```

Then we have something like:

```
|-hello
|     -HelloWorldJNI.java
|     -HelloWorldJNI.h
|     -HelloWorldJNI.cpp
|hello.jar
|libnative.so
```

To test the library:

`Example.java`

```
import hello.HelloWorldJNI;

public class Example{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorldJNI().sayHello();
  }
}
```

To compile and run:

```
javac -cp "HelloWorldJNI.jar" Example.java
java -cp . -Djava.library.path=./ Example
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/HelloWorldJNI
    at Example.main(Example.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.HelloWorldJNI
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Instead when I try:

```
java -cp "HelloWorldJNI.jar" -Djava.library.path=./ Example
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
```

When I try:

```
java -cp ".;HelloWorldJNI.jar" -Djava.library.path=./ Example
```

I get this again:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Look inside `hello.jar` and you'll see what is the problem.

Comment: (as you probably know), `ClassNotFoundException` means that the `Example` class is not present in your classpath. When you run `java -cp ".;HelloWorldJNI.jar" -Djava.library.path=./ Example` . Is `Example.class` present in the current folder?

Comment: also- are you on windows on linux (or cygwin)? are you using the right delimiter for `-cp`?(`;` vs `:`)

Comment: @Daniele I an on Ubuntu18.04 LTS. Yes, I was using the wrong delimiter. Example.class is present in the current folder. Now I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: For the UnsatisfiedLinkError, maybe use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`

Comment: The library path is specified with -Djava.library.path, isn't it? Also specifying LD_LIBRARY didn't work

The problem was, that the function name generated by javac -h wasn't correct. 
Instead of `Java_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello` it should've been `Java_hello_HelloWorldJNI_sayHello`

Comment: @Daniele I'm trying to use the library from the command line here. Any ideas on how I could use the jar and .so file in a java gradle project?